# How can i detect only changed values in angular forms?

Tags: angular, formbuilder

In angular forms, how can I detect **only** changed fields whose values are different than their initial values?

Comment: What have you tried can you share your code?

Comment: You can use form.valueChanges or form('controlName').valueChanges observable where you can listen for changes in the form's value

Answer (score 2):

Use [valueChanges](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) to detect updates in form controls:

form:

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

or specific control:

```
this.myForm.controls['controlName'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup , FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup;
  initalFormValue: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
       ........
        });
      this.initalFormValue = this.form;
  }
}
```

You will save the initial form value in another form group and then you can able to compare each other

Answer (score -1):

You will need to store the initial value

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  foo: ['bar'],
});

this.initialFormValue = this.form.value;
```

Later you can compare the value to `this.initialFormValue`

---

**Edit:**

You could install a valueChange Subscription on every form control (you could do that with a loop for each forms control), which uses the `scan` operator.

```
fooControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  scan((acc, curr) => { acc[1] = curr; return acc; }, [fooControl.value, fooControl.value]),
).subscripe(([initial, current]) => console.log("Has foo the initial value?", initial === current));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't  want to get changes by comparing field by field, I want to get them automatically, is there a solution?

Comment: I added another approach